# Xamarin.Forms Android App crash when first launch after install or update

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have this issue when first launch my app after installing it or update new version then my app will crashing. It's only happening once time and not appear on debug mode just only in release.
I have include AppCenter Crash into my app and then find this stack traces but im not understand it. Hope you guy could help me find the problem:

```
java.lang.Class.newInstance Class.java
android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateReceiver AppComponentFactory.java:110
androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateReceiver
android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver ActivityThread.java:3773
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400 ActivityThread.java:225
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage ActivityThread.java:1876
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage Handler.java:107
android.os.Looper.loop Looper.java:359
android.app.ActivityThread.main ActivityThread.java:7418
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Method.java
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run RuntimeInit.java:492
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main ZygoteInit.java:935
```

Comment: Could you provide the information for the stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for supporting me, i have found the problem and solved it. Turn out it's all because i've include FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver to AndroidManifest which i'm not using anymore.
After erasing that and uninstalling the AppCenter.Push nuget then everything is fine for now.

Answer (score 0):

Based your AppCenter Crash data you use AndroidX, and you need to change your `Tabbar.xaml` and `Toolbar.xaml` and other layout you have with `AndroidX` class.

[image]

Use this [AndroidX Class Mappings](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings) to update your layout.

Comment: I have change namespace as you said but it's cant create the archive file because the packaging process failed